# elixir simple nosql db with hashing

Tags: elixir

I'm writing a very simple distributed cache in elixir(just a PoC, nothing really important). 
the idea is simple, i have n nodes (each one of them contains a region or cache partition) and 1 orchestrator node. 
every request goes to the orchestrator, orchestrator selects a node (based on key) and writes to it.
that is: if req is a PUT, orchestrator calculates a node and writes to it; 
if req is a GET, orchestrator calculates where that key should be and reads from that node. 
overall, the system is working. also i have implemented a failover/takeover scheme for orchestrator layer.

my question is:
the function that selects a node is completely stateless(no previous state is needed as i'm using a [hash mod n] based algorithm which obviously given the same key, returns always the same node). 
that is to say, every req is completely indepent of each other. 
in iex, i can spawn 1000 processes and do put/get requests in parallel as i said before node selection is completly stateless( for this example asume 500 will do "get" requests and 500 will do "put" requests).

however i'm not 100% sure of this scheme.

do i need to serialize reqs through an intermediary process which receives req, gets/puts to/from given node, and reply to client ?

if i do that, i'm turning that process into a bottleneck, but, on the other hand i'm ensuring "proper" sequential access.

with my actual scheme, every req is independent of each other(could be) and therefore access is no sequential.